# $Ker(A-\lambda_j)^{k_j},j=1,\cdots p$ span the whole space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In finite dimensional vector space $V$,suppose $\lambda_j,j=1,\cdots,p$ are the eigenvalues with multiplicity $m_1,,\cdots,m_p$, is that true that

$Ker(A-\lambda_j)^{k_j},j=1,\cdots p$ 
span the whole space $V$? $k_j$ is the least index such that
$Ker(A-\lambda_j)^{k_j}=Ker(A-\lambda_j)^{k_j+1}$

Comment: Does $A$ have any eigenvalues other than $\lambda_j$ over the algebraic closure of the base field? If yes, then the answer is "no". If no, then the answer is "yes", and this is a consequence of the Jordan normal form (although, probably, also a lemma in proving the latter).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$ (or some other algebraically closed field), yes: this is true.  In particular, $\ker(A - \lambda_j)^{k_j}$ is the [generalized eigenspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Overview_and_definition) associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$.

Proving that this is the case is equivalent to establishing that every transformation has a [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

Comment: how to show the basis in $Ker(A-\lambda_j)^{k_j}$ are linearly independent

Comment: I don't understand your question.  By definition, a basis is linearly independent.

Comment: I mean the basis in each $Ker(A-\lambda)^{k_y}$ together are linearly independent

Comment: It's enough to show that if $(A - \lambda)^k x = (A - \mu)^k x$ with $\mu \neq \lambda$, then $x = 0$.